# undefined reference during AVR building, linker error

Tags: avr-gcc

I'm trying to compile and link AVR based program in Atmel Studio (7). I have got the error message in linking phase.

I am doing this procedure first time with this software, because I got this software for maintenance. And I heard that this software have been succesfully built previously in "some environment". I installed the newest Atmel Studio, and picked project file, and selected correct processor. After the linking phase started, the error message appeared regarding undefined reference.

> Building target: 16k.elf      Invoking: AVR/GNU Linker : 5.4.0
>         "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-gcc.exe"
>   -o 16k.elf  DanskOFP.o adc_drv.o   -Wl,-Map="16k.map" -Wl,--start-group  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega164p -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.2.209\gcc\dev\atmega164p"
>   C:\Projektit\V2.34\DanskOFP\Atmega164p\Makefile(118,1): error: recipe
>   for target '16k.elf' failed       DanskOFP.o: In function `CPRX':
>
> C:\Projektit\V2.34\DanskOFP\Atmega164p\Makefile(118,1): error: recipe
>   for target '16k.elf' failed       DanskOFP.o: In function `CPRX':
>   C:\Projektit\V2.34\DanskOFP\DanskOFP.c(1507,1): error: undefined
>   reference to`__eewr_byte_m164p'
>   C:\Projektit\V2.34\DanskOFP\DanskOFP.c(1507,1): error: undefined
>   reference to `__eewr_byte_m164p'
>   C:\Projektit\V2.34\DanskOFP\DanskOFP.c(1507,1): error: undefined
>   reference to`__eewr_byte_m164p'
>   C:\Projektit\V2.34\DanskOFP\DanskOFP.c(1507,1): error: undefined
>   reference to `__eewr_byte_m164p'
>   C:\Projektit\V2.34\DanskOFP\DanskOFP.c(1507,1): error: undefined
>   reference to`__eewr_byte_m164p'

I expect that the internal definition regarding "__eewr_byte_m164p" should be found from somewhere, but I have no glue, has something changed between AVR versions, or should  the definition presented some new practise ?

Comment: Do a full text search for the missing symbol. The `__` prefix hints it is a linker defined symbol - look into linker scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's a function from avr-libc, namely the target-specific function called from [`eeprom_write_byte()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__eeprom.html#ga682e0b2ca0badd47e1e30e61617e1361). Make sure that avr-libc in in the build/link path.